# How good is confidentiality with physical mail forwarding companies?

Tags: identity, confidentiality, identification

I want to use a mail forwarding company that can receive mail for me and forward it to another address.
I found many places that do this, but I am worried that eventually my stalker would find out that I use this p.o.box, call the p.o.box staff pretending to be me, and get my real address.
How can I minimize this risk?
Any forwarding company that practises strict identity check over the phone/emails?
World-wide ok.

Comment: You could try that for yourself by asking a friend to try some social engineering on them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any guarantee of this. Even with the best intentions, the staff could be duped by social engineering.

You can't really minimise the risk any further than using a reputable forwarding company, but my advice would be to call them and ask about their account security practices. They may also be able to set an account note about your situation, e.g. "customer requests that no information, especially forwarding address, is revealed to anyone who calls in relation to the account, even if it's the customer themselves". At least that way you have some peace of mind over the matter.